# Playing music in python using playsound module

Tags: python, python-playsound

I am using the playsound.playsound module in python to play a music file stored on my PC,but the problem is that I want to decrease the volume of the sound, is there any particular parameter to insert in the query?

The output/result is volume controlled like if in the function `playsound("filename", volume=x)`, is there an actual parameter for volume, without changing the module.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I skimmed the repo and couldn't locate anything referring to sound levels. Sorry. Repo: https://github.com/TaylorSMarks/playsound/blob/master/playsound.py

Comment: @pinegulf No Issues. Thank you for assisting me!

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)